# Python 3 PermissionError: [WinError 32] The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process

Tags: python, python-3.x, file

I have two folder in the desktop. I want to rename (i.e cut and paste) to Screenshots folder whenever there is exactly one file in the captured folder.
But when I run the program (there is no files in either directory) and paste one file into the src (i.e Captured folder), it throws an error message. what i am missing here?

```
import os

dest= 'C:/Users/rajini raja/Desktop/Screenshots/'
src = 'C:/Users/rajini raja/Desktop/Captured/'

while True:
    if len(os.listdir(src)) == 1:
        os.rename(src + 'capture.png', dest + 'capture.png')
        break
```

the error message shows as

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\rajini raja\Desktop\os_rename.py", line 13, in <module> 
os.rename(src + 'capture.png', file_path + 'capture.png')
PermissionError: [WinError 32] The process cannot access the file because it 
is being used by another process: 'C:/Users/rajini 
raja/Desktop/Captured/capture.png' -> 'C:/Users/rajini 
raja/Desktop/Screenshots/capture.png'
```

Comment: How do you do the paste? That the pasted file in fact being used? There isn't much you can do at the python level. This is a windows sharing violation.

Comment: right click and then paste. Is there any other way to do it?